# Restarting perl cgi script

Tags: perl, cgi

After searching around I found this command `exec($^X, $0, @ARGV);` which restarts a perl script. However when I do this my script runs normally but has `Content-Type: text/html` infront of the expected output. I was wondering if this was the correct way to restart my perl cgi script.

EDIT:

```
elsif (defined param("again")){
    exec($^X, $0, @ARGV);
    exit;
}
```

When the script restarts it's supposed to print `My guess is: 50` but it prints `Content-Type: text/html My guess is: 50`

Comment: Without more information, it's hard to say. But probably not. Backtrack a bit and explain your problem and what you've tried as a solution, and we might be able to give an answer. See [ask]

Comment: @Sobrique My problem is restarting the script and the solution I tried is `exec($^X, $0, @ARGV);`

Comment: That sounds an awful lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - it doesn't make a lot of sense to restart a script like that, especially not when in a `cgi` context where scripts are spawned by your httpd.

Comment: @Sobrique Ah, I see what you mean. I am coding a game which has the option to play again. Basically when they click play again I want the script to restart. Is using the aforementioned approach correct?

Comment: But on a web page? Why not instead just refresh the page, because that'll start a new instance of the script anyway. If you're not doing it via a web page, then a `while` loop is much more efficient.

Comment: @Sobrique Thanks got it

Answer (score 2):

The first time you output it, it is used as a header (and not displayed), the second time as part of the content.

Add a parameter to @ARGV so that you can check whether the script was already restarted and therefore the header should not be sent anymore.

EDIT: I have just seen what is your intended use for this script. In an online game context, it would of course be preferable to refresh, redirect or simply provide a link or form submission to run the script again.

Solutions like this, where you restart a script (or run another) within the same http connection rather make sense for workhorse or surveillance scripts, for example to keep the memory footprint low. But it is a very rarely seen animal.